# java.util.InputMismatchException HEADACHE

Tags: java, file, input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class GardinierPayrollP2
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  // int id;  //i.d. number
  // double hrsworkd; //hours worked
   double wkspay = 0.00;  //total amount before tax for an individual employee
   double netpay = 0.00; //net pay to an individual after tax
   double runningTotal = 0.00; //total amount of paid salaries
   double runningNetTotal = 0.00; //net total after tax 
   double runningTaxTotal = 0.00; //total taxes payed 
   double levelA = 12.00;
   double levelB = 14.50;
   double levelC = 16.00;
   double levelD = 20.00;
   //String name; //employees First Name
   //char level; //level of payment for employee
   final double taxRate = .08; //tax rate @ 8%
   double taxes = 0.00; //dollar amount of taxes payed
  
  
  File employees = new File("employees.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(employees);
  
  
  
  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
    
   String name = inputFile.nextLine();
   int id = inputFile.nextInt();
   char level = inputFile.next().charAt(0);
   double hrsworkd = inputFile.nextDouble();
   
   System.out.println(name + id + level + hrsworkd);
  }

 }
}
```

This is what I'm working with. Second year of computer science. Not very versed in troubleshooting the errors yet. I know theres an input error. I just can't tell why. DrJava's output for it is to print the first four lines of the info and then throw the error. heres the output

```
> run GardinierPayrollP2
Rose Nylund901A10.0
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at GardinierPayrollP2.main(GardinierPayrollP2.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
>
```

Here's the input file

```
Rose Nylund
901
A
10.0
Dorothy Zbornak
534
D
11.5
Blanche Deveraux
109
B
5.0
Sophia Petrillo
729
C
2.5
```

What am I doing wrong?|

Comment: What line of your code is it throwing the error on?

Comment: it's a run time error i guess? After i run it it prints the first while loop of data and then errors out

Comment: Your output prints each element on a new line, but your code shows that the data for each person should be on one line, smooshed together.

Comment: I'm testing the program to see if it will print all the info with in the input file. I can't seem to get it to execute the while loop more than once. it will print the first employees info then it sends the error. When I changed it to String name = inputFile.next();  instead of String name = inputFile.nextLine(); it printed nothing but the error no data from the input file at all

Comment: `nextLine()` is consuming the remainder (empty) of the line after the `nextDouble()`.

Comment: Is there something I should use other than nextLine() or nextDouble() to make it return more data?